# In a mapbox gl js layer of type 'fill': Can we control the stroke thickness?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

According to https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/ a layer with type='fill' draws "a filled polygon with an **optional stroked border**".

```
type: 'fill',
paint: {
  'fill-color': 'orange',
  'fill-opacity': 0.5,
  'fill-outline-color': 'red'
}
```

The stroke around the polygon is drawn, but very thin, so it is hardly noticable.

**Question:** Is there a way to draw a stronger, thicker, stroke line (stroke) around the polygon?

I also found https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4087 which argues, that the settings are confusing as they are now. I agree with that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to this comment the stroke is currently limited to 1px width (you can't change the width):
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4088#issuecomment-285801635

You could use an additional `line` layer (using the same source) on top of the polygon `fill` layer.
This way you would be able to draw a thicker stroke around the polygon using [line-width](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#paint-line-line-width) (for the `line` layer).

Answer (score 1):

In the fill mode, you can't set the width. If you want to accomplish that, you will need to create a line mode layer after the fill mode layer with the same source. Example here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/